# PHP 5.5 mysql 5.6 version mismatch

Tags: centos, mysql, php

I have Centos installed.

In error logs I get the error

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch.
```

I have PHP 5.5 and mysql 5.6 installed.

It was suggested to use

```
sudo yum install php-mysqlnd
```

However, it gave error:

```
Processing Conflict: php55w-common-5.5.38-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5
Finished Dependency Resolution
```

**UPDATE**

Installed mysqlnd- mismatch problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the php-mysqlnd found in your repository is not 5.5. To install this package in the correct version, try running

```
sudo yum install php55w-mysqlnd
```

Comment: Installed mysqlnd, mismatch problem is not solved

Comment: Ah, this is due to the fact that php55w-mysql and php55w-mysqlnd both contain the same packages, so this will not resolve your issue.

Taking a second look at this issue, it looks as if there are still some MySQL packages which haven't been updated.

Run `sudo yum update mysql*`, see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, prematurely hit enter. Updated the comment.

Comment: Gave `No packages marked for update`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to restart the server. Thank you!!

Comment: Good to hear, sorry for the confusion!